# Presentacion de datos en forma tabular c++

Tags: dev-c++

Necesito hacer un programa que me haga descuentos a mi salario y presentar la salida de forma tabular, pero no se como hacerlo. Intente hacerlo por matrix pero se como rellenarla con los datos que necesito.

```
    for(int i=0; i<em; i++)
    {
        cod=cont;
        cont++;
        cout<<cod<<" -->Ingrese su nombre: "<<endl;
        cin>>nom;
        cout<<"Ingrese su apellido: "<<endl;
        cin>>ap;
        cout<<"Ingrese su numero de cedula: "<<endl;
        cin>>ced;
    cout<<"Cuantas horas trabajo esta semana? "<<endl;
    cin>>ht;
    sb=h*ht;
    //sb=s*4;
    //Descuentos
    sfs=sb*0.061;
    afp=0.0387*sb;
    td=sb-sfs-afp;
    sn=sb-td;
    if (sb>=46500){

        isr=0.185*sb;
        td=sb-sfs-afp-isr;
        sn=sb-td;
    }


    cout<<" Total de horas semanales: "<<ht<<endl;
    cout<<"Salario bruto es: "<<sb<<endl;
    cout<<"SFS: "<<sfs<<endl;
    cout<<"AFP: "<<afp<<endl;
    cout<<"ISR: "<<isr<<endl;
    cout<<"Total de descuento: "<<td<<endl;
    cout<<"Su salario neto es: "<<sn<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;

}

    return 0;

}
```

Funciona solo que quiero que el resultado sea en forma tabular.

---

Algo así:

```
Nombre.   Apellido.   Descuento.  Salario
Luis.     Ramiro.         $3000.   $67000
Pedro.    Palote.         $2000.    $1200
Juan      feliz.           $120.    $4000
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias dibujar, o poner una foto de como deseas el resultado?

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Dónde quieres mostrar la información? ¿En la consola? ¿qué es eso de _matrix_ de lo que hablas? En tu código no hay nada especial. Aclara mejor lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola. Quiero que el resultado aparezca en forma de tabla.

Answer (score 1):

La salida por consola en C++ no está pensada para mostrarse de manera tabular, es por eso que ofrece muy pocas facilidades para mostrar datos de esa manera. Sin embargo, hay esperanza si…

- Eres poco exigente con la salida: Usa [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip).
- Puedes esperar a mediados de año para usar [C++20 format](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r10.html).
- Puedes usar librerías externas como [tabulate](https://github.com/p-ranav/tabulate).

---

#### Usando `<iomanip>`

Esta cabecera tiene varias utilidades para manipular cómo se muestra la salida por consola, puedes alinear texto a izquierda y derecha estableciendo una anchura, por ejemplo:

```
std::cout
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "Total de horas semanales: " << ht << '\n'
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "Salario bruto es: "         << sb << '\n'
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "SFS: "                      << sfs << '\n'
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "AFP: "                      << afp << '\n'
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "ISR: "                      << isr << '\n'
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "Total de descuento: "       << td << '\n'
    << std::right << std::setw(26)
    << "Su salario neto es: "       << sn << '\n'
    << '\n' << std::endl;
```

El código anterior muestra una salida como esta:

> ```
> Total de horas semanales: … 
>         Salario bruto es: …
>                      SFS: …
>                      AFP: …
>                      ISR: …
>       Total de descuento: …
>       Su salario neto es: …
> ```

Me gustaría que observaras que sólo es necesaria una llamada a `std::cout` y un solo `std::endl`.

#### La cabecera [`<format>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) de C++20.

En el estándar que se prevee aprobar este año, un código como el siguiente produciría la misma salida que el anterior:

```
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "Total de horas semanales:", ht);
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "Salario bruto es:", sb);
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "SFS:", sfs);
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "AFP:", afp);
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "ISR:", isr);
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "Total de descuento:", td);
std::format("{:>26}: {}\n", "Su salario neto es:", sn);
```

Quiero destacar que se puede conseguir el mismo efecto con una sola llamada a `std::format`.

#### La librería `tabulate`.

La librería (del usuario de GitHub [p-ranav](https://github.com/p-ranav)), permite crear tablas, este ejemplo de su propio GitHub:

```
#include <tabulate/table.hpp>
using namespace tabulate;

int main() {
  Table movies;
  movies.add_row({"S/N", "Movie Name", "Director", "Estimated Budget", "Release Date"});
  movies.add_row({"tt1979376", "Toy Story 4", "Josh Cooley", "$200,000,000", "21 June 2019"});
  movies.add_row({"tt3263904", "Sully", "Clint Eastwood", "$60,000,000", "9 September 2016"});
  movies.add_row({"tt1535109", "Captain Phillips", "Paul Greengrass", "$55,000,000", " 11 October 2013"});

  // center align 'Director' column
  movies.column(2).format()
    .font_align(FontAlign::center);

  // right align 'Estimated Budget' column
  movies.column(3).format()
    .font_align(FontAlign::right);

  // right align 'Release Date' column
  movies.column(4).format()
    .font_align(FontAlign::right);

  // center-align and color header cells
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    movies[0][i].format()
      .font_color(Color::yellow)
      .font_align(FontAlign::center)
      .font_style({FontStyle::bold});
  }

  std::cout << movies << std::endl;
}
```

Genera una salida como esta:

[image]

Comment: Excelente, gracias.